# React SPA - GTM Analytics React-Helmet Previous Page Title

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, single-page-application, google-tag-manager, react-helmet

I am using Google Tag Manager to push pageview events to the datalayer for Analytics tracking. This is happening in **componentDidMount()** (and sometimes **componentWillReceiveProps()** if I am listening for query string parameter changes with the location prop using withRouter).

I am using [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) to dynamically update my title and other tags as components change.

I have noticed an issue that I am getting the improper page title in Analytics. It's frequently showing the page title of the previous page, instead of the one I am currently on. It appears that react-helmet is not updating the  tag until after **componentDidMount()**.

**Page View Event Function Example**

*My analytics tag in GTM is called every time this event is pushed to the data layer*

```js
const firePageViewEvent = () => {
      console.log("Pageview event fired (from tracking script)");

      if (window && window.dataLayer) {
          console.log("window and dataLayer exist, pushing pageview event.");
          let dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          dataLayer.push({
              'event': 'reactPageViewEvent'
          });
      } else {
          console.log("window or dataLater does not exist, cannot push pageview event.");
      }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that wrapping the function in a setTimeOut() function with a 0ms delay does indeed work to ensure that the event is only pushed after react-helmet has a chance to do its thing.

This allows me to consistently get the *current page title* in Analytics.

[See github issue comment](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/189#issuecomment-336292754)

**Updated Function**

```js
const firePageViewEvent = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Pageview event fired (from tracking script)");

        if (window && window.dataLayer) {
            console.log("window and dataLayer exist, pushing pageview event.");
            let dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            dataLayer.push({
                'event': 'reactPageViewEvent'
            });
        } else {
            console.log("window or dataLater does not exist, cannot push pageview event.");
        }
    }, 0);
};
```

Comment: There may be a better solution now, but over a year ago this was the only workaround to be found.

Comment: that issue is still there ... https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/189 !
Let's have a dataLayer.push({'event':'pageTitleUpdated'} occur when it is done
Or push values to be used by GA when available and configure GA to use these instead of the defaults DOM values

Comment: 10x Matthew, these React / GTAGs and Helmets are driving me crazy!!!